# How to load .exe file within C# Program?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a C# program where I need to display a Virtual keyboard (which is another program in WPF with C#). As I am new to WPF I am not able to integrate my C# program and externally downloaded WPF program for virtual keyboard.

I thought of building a setup file and calling it within C# program using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Default Company Name\Keyboard\Keyboard\Wosk.exe");
```

But this throws an error. But when I download any other .exe file for a virtual key board the same code calls the .exe file on button click.

Can anyone let me know how can I build an .exe file for Visual Studio so that its .exe can be called from another program on button click?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Please provide more details

Comment: If you have source access, why not directly use the libraries? Much easier than inter process communications.

Comment: I am having this project as a WPF project    http://www.codeplex.com/wosk

Comment: I am getting debug error

Comment: Are the 2 Wosk Dll's in the same directory as the executable?

Comment: yes. I have created a setup using Visual Studios setup wizard and then installed on my local system. I am calling that .exe.  Although let me tell you that when i call the .exe I downloaded from Internet it runs without fail. But the problem with that is that its not a customized one that I wish to have. You can have a look here http://www.codeplex.com/wosk

Answer (score 0):

First, maybe [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/69526b52-bb7c-422f-a9bc-00d2a79d40d4/passing-data-between-applications-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral) link can help you.

Second, if you have the keyboard code you can create him as dll file and then you can return data from him with public function.
By this way, you can add the keyboard to your app, open the keyboard easily and send\recieve data.